# Flash CS5...elements are snapping to pixels while moving?

Tags: actionscript-3, image

I have an imported png in a 'info_icon' symbol.
I have another imported png in a 'info_content' symbol.

I have some code that allows you to drag an instance of a 'map' symbol around. Inside this map symbol are instances of 'info_icon' and 'info_content'.

When I drag the map slowly, I can see the info_icon instances and info_content instances, jiggle ever so slightly...I think to line up to pixels.

I'm trying to figure out how to stop that. I'm looking at the pixelSnapping property and it doesn't seem to be helping...perhaps I'm using it wrong.

`info_button_mc.pixelSnapping = PixelSnapping.NEVER;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to set smoothing to true on the bitmap.

Try setting scaleX to 0.999 or something like that (in other words, close enough to 1 that you can't tell it's being scaled).

For some reason smoothing doesn't seem to actually get applied unless the scale of the object is something other than 1.

Remember you should be working with bitmaps here, so make sure to export the PNG for ActionScript (right click on PNG->properties) and give it a class name and then:

```
var bitmap : Bitmap = new Bitmap(new YourPNG(), PixelSnapping.NEVER);
addChild(bitmap);
bitmap.smoothing = true;
bitmap.scaleX = 0.999;
```

Comment: @Pixel Elephant... I'm loading my images dynamically into a Loader class. How would I use your technique in that instance (no pun intended)?

Comment: `var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
   bmp = Bitmap(eLoader.content);
   bmp.smoothing = true;
   bmp.scaleX = 0.999;
   bmp.scaleY = 0.999;
   this.addChild(bmp);`  This worked, but you can tell that the image is ever so slightly blurry. I have rendered text in the image so you can totally tell. Is this the only way to stop the annoying jittering/pixelsnapping?

Comment: You either can have perfectly sharp image or the ability to move it slowly on subpixel level.

Answer (score 0):

Is info_button_mc a MovieClip or a Bitmap? In addition to what Pixel Elephant suggested, make sure the cacheAsBitmap property is false on the bitmap and its container (if the container is involved with the bitmap's movement). CacheAsBitmap will always pixel snap and it's worth noting that any filters you may have active automatically set cacheAsBitmap to true.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the scale to 0.999 which will result in a blurry image, try rendering your image at double resolution (as in the source image: png, bitmap, whatever - make it twice as big in each dimension as what you actually want in the swf) and then setting the scale to .5. In my experience, this is the best of both worlds. That said, it still may not be perfect enough for text - but it is substantially better quality than setting the scale to 0.999.